# Accessing Twitter API with Twarc in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, twarc2

I am having issues with the the twarc package in python. Basically i have tried following the guide from this website.
https://twarc-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twarc2_en_us/

However iam not able to make a simple query like

twarch2 search blacklivesmatter

i get the wrong syntax error.

Does anyone know how this could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote exactly the same as here, then there is a syntax error in your command. You wrote ***twarch2***, but it must be `twarc2`. And also try to use double quotes, so try this

`twarc2 search "blacklivesmatter"`